# Do Sails.js and Waterline support utf8bm4 charset?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have to pass emojis from app to backend and store these emojis in a MySQL database.
I tried to migrate the entire database to utf8bm4 charset, but I had problems with the Sessions table (sid is VARCHAR(255) and utf8bm4 charset allows indexed columns to be a maximum of VARCHAR(191)).
How can I configure a single table to be utf8bm4 and do I have to update the model or queries to deal with the new charset?
I know it's not a well defined question but any inputs will be appreciated.